# Tracking and instrumenting memory accesses for Java application

Tags: java, memory-management, profiling, instrumentation

I am trying to track and instrument memory loads for Java programs.
A very simple usecase is to print all the memory accessed by load instruction in a program while it is running. I want to do this using a lightweight mechanism like Intel PIN because I will restrict its memory to cause memory pressure. One option is to use simics, but I don't know how simics reacts when I constrain memory using cgroups for example.

I have built this tool for C applications using PIN but PIN doesn't work for Java, is there any similar tool that I can use for Java?

I tried using PIN with Java along with the -follow_execv flag, since PIN doesn't have access to the binary it seems like it can't work. I confirmed this with the community. I briefly tried to use DynamoRIO but that didn't seem to work for my usecase as there is a delay in the printing of the assembly instructions and I need them to be instrumented when the instructions are executed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.